# SQL Select Sub Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, subquery

I have the following database tables

```
User          List
------        ------
userId (PK)   listId (PK)
fullName      description
              addedById (FK with userId in User table)
              modifiedById (FK with userId in User table)
```

I need to pull out all data from the **List table**, but instead of showing the IDs for **addedById** and **modifiedById**, I need to pull the **fullName** from the **User** table.

This query works, and gives me the data I need. However, I'm not sure if there is a better way of constructing this query? I'm not keen on having multiple sub select queries within my main select query, mainly because of performance issues.

```
select t1.[description], 
   t1.addedById, 
   t1.modifiedById, 
   (select fullName from dbo.User where userId = t1.addedById) as [AddedByUser],
   (select fullName from dbo.User where userId = t1.modifiedById) as [ModifiedByUser]

from dbo.List t1
```

I'd really appreciate if anyone could suggest improvements to the query, or advise to keep as is.

Thanks.

Comment: Do LEFT JOIN's instead.

Comment: Your query is fine, assuming there is an index on `userId`.  Another approach is `LEFT JOIN`.  Performance should be pretty similar for either approach.

Comment: Off-topic for SO.   I suggest posting on CodeReview.

Comment: Why would this question be down voted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more standard SQL method would be:

```
SELECT t1.description,
    t1.addedById,
    t1.modifiedById,
    add.fullName AS [AddedByUser],
    mod.fullName AS [ModifiedByUser]
FROM dbo.List t1
LEFT JOIN dbo.User add
    ON add.userId = t1.addedById
LEFT JOIN dbo.User mod
    ON mod.userID = t1.modifiedById
```

However, I suspect this will perform identically to your query and probably has an identical execution plan.  The only real advantage to this method is that it's easier to expand.  For example, if you wanted to add new columns from the User table this would be easier.

As @Gordon notes, performance should be fine if there's an index on the fields you're joining with.

Comment: This alternative approach is very useful. There are indexes on the fields I am joining with, and I haven't noticed any difference with both approaches.

Answer (score 1):

Is that double join with same table bothering you? It's not slow, its preferred way of doing it instead making the linked subquery.

I am assuming you got indexes on PK and both FK.

Only thing you can minimize is to lessen the number of joined rows. You can do that
by either using the left inner join or filtering in the end with where clause stating both keys you use in join must be not null

I can write both examples for you but this should be self explanatory.

Other mayor thing you can do is to PRESELECT values from users. For example if you have a shit ton of users, and you know only few of them can be in either role. And you can filter which ones by some column in Users you haven't listed, even better if that column has an index.

Then you can maybe profit from pre-selecting only those users and then joining to selection result. Either by temp table if both can be pre-selected or by making a select on spot instead joining to the entire table. Not sure about numbers we are dealing with here for this to become relevant..